# Django - Create Users with specific permission

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django 2 - python3

my model: simplified

```
class School_info(models.Model):

    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    school_address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    school_sector = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=)
    school_field = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices='') 
    school_size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices='')
    school_phone = PhoneField(blank=True, help_text='Contact phone number')
    school_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name

class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    course_description = models.TextField(default='')
    course_scope = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

class Homework(models.Model): 
    homework_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    homework_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    homework_address = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    homework_description = models.CharField(max_length=700, default='')
    homework_avaliablility =  models.CharField(max_length=8, choices='')
    homework_criticality = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.homework_name
```

This is My needed data, I want the Admin to create 2 type of Users, and he is only able to Create Courses and HomeWorks.

Teacher and Student.

The Teacher can view the Course and the homework.

The Student can view the Assigned Homework and the School info Without the Course Info.

Only the Admin Can Create A Teacher Account And Assign it to the Course and Can view the School Info and HomeWork.

The Student Can View The Assigned Homework and and Submit it the Teacher can request the Homework to be RE-DO.

I got confused where I would put the Account Creation and How to make Sure that no Other Teacher or Student to View Other If they Do not have the Permission and The Assignment.

Weather to Choice ManyToMany or ForeignKey.

The Admin Can Add As many homeworks to the Course as he Wishes

Admin:

1- create School

2-  Create Course and Homeworks For a Specific Course.

3-  create Teacher $ Student Account

4-  Assign the Course To the Teacher

4-  Assign the Homework To Student

Teacher:

1- View School Info

2- View Course + Homeworks Info

3- Request Homework Re-Do

Student:

1- View Homework

2- Submit it

3- Able to RE-do it

I'm new to django any clue would be helpful.

Thank you.